# printing specific variable in c a specific way

Tags: c, cs50

After getting all my header files properly "linked" I finally reached the point of being able to compile my code correctly. When I did mariov1.c (code shown below) I used a test input of 20, the result was a printout of 3 hashmarks then the display of my cmd line like this

`###[xvp@localhost ~]$`

now It was supposed to have an output of 21 spaces and 2 hashmarks adding a hashmark and subtracting a space each row until the number of hashmarks = usrHeight (essentially it is not actually setup to be determined by the number of hashes but it still works that way).Should have looked something like this.

```
How High?
10
constructing...
         ##
        ###
       ####
      #####
     ######
    #######
   ########
  #########
 ##########
###########
```

This would keep it right aligned.

mariov1.c source

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int usrHeight = 0;
    int levelCounter = 0;
    int paddIt = usrHeight - 1;
    int hashCounter = 2;


    do 
    {
        printf("How high?\n");
        int usrHeight = GetInt();
    }
    while ( usrHeight > 23 || usrHeight < 0);
    if ( usrHeight >= 0 && usrHeight <= 23);
    {
        printf("constructing...\n");

    }
    for (levelCounter = 0; levelCounter <= usrHeight; levelCounter++)
    {
            printf("%.*s\n", paddIt, "");
            for (int i = 0; i <= hashCounter; i++)
                putchar('#'); 
            paddIt = paddIt - 1;
            hashCounter = hashCounter + 1;
    }

}
```

I made a second attempt after this blunder using another do while loop with a for loop in the middle of it (pretty sure i did it wrong) but it just filled the terminal with hashes continously so I'm not sure where to go at this point.

Here's mariov2.c source

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int usrHeight = 0;
    int levelCounter = 0;
    int paddIt = usrHeight - 1;
    int hashCounter = 2;


    do 
    {
        printf("How high?\n");
        int usrHeight = GetInt();
    }
    while ( usrHeight > 23 || usrHeight < 0);
    if ( usrHeight >= 0 && usrHeight <= 23);
    {
        printf("constructing...\n");

    }
    //doing a test to see if this do while loop will handle this appropriatelly
    do
    {
        printf("%.*s\n", paddIt, "");
            for (int i = 0; i <= hashCounter; i++)
        {
            putchar('#');
            paddIt = paddIt - 1;
            hashCounter = hashCounter + 1;
            levelCounter = levelCounter + 1;
        }   
    }
    while ( levelCounter <= usrHeight );
    //commented area part of original code
    //for (levelCounter = 0; levelCounter <= usrHeight; levelCounter++)
    //{
        //  printf("%.*s", paddIt, "");
        //  for (int i = 0; i <= hashCounter; i++)
        //      putchar('#'); 
        //  paddIt = paddIt - 1;
        //  hashCounter = hashCounter + 1;
    //}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to notice is that the `usrHeight` you are using in the loop is always `0` because in the segment

```
do 
{
    printf("How high?\n");
    int usrHeight = GetInt();
}
while ( usrHeight > 23 || usrHeight < 0);
```

The `usrHeight` is local to this while scope. Once the control is outside this scope and you use `usrHeight` it is actually the variable which you defined in the scope of function main. Remove `int` from `int usrHeight = GetInt();`

Also you have computed the `paddIt` variable before you have actually initialized it with a value using `GetInt ()`.

Comment: This makes sense I brought my laptop to work today I'll see what my edits to the code do, here is what I've changed so far.(What you're telling me makes sense, but I'm a little dense this morning.) so I would like to see if I have interpreted your answer correctly.

Comment: After i made the changes the things were looking fine.

Comment: remove the int from usrHeight in the do loop, and then after usrHeight  = GetInt() i set paddIt = usrHeight - 1;?